# Do color transformation in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, colors

I would like to do some standard color transformation on a Loader object (Which is used to display a picture) like Sepia, Black & White etc...

I'm currently using methods like this one :

```
var colorTransformer:ColorTransform = selectedItm.transform.colorTransform; 
colorTransformer.redMultiplier = 1/6;
colorTransformer.greenMultiplier = 1/5;
colorTransformer.blueMultiplier = 1/3;
selectedItm.transform.colorTransform = colorTransformer;
```

But I dont know how obtain a Sepia or a Black and White effect. Is there a function to do this ? If not is there some kind of database which contains "multiplier" to obtains effect ?

Comment: Hey I'm not aware of any way to directly choose one of these styles or of any dictionaries/databases of styles to values but this will probably help to figure it out yourself: http://www.kelvinluck.com/2009/04/colortransform-explorer/

Comment: Also black and white you'd just want to reduce the saturation to 0 at kevinlucks site he has a link in the comments about an HSL class.

Comment: you should use a pixel bender filter for this:  http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1536019#

Comment: Can you update your answer with a list of ColorMatrix filters if you have solved this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to explore to fine tune a sepia filter:

```
var sepia = new flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter();
sepia.matrix = [0.3930000066757202, 0.7689999938011169, 
0.1889999955892563, 0, 0, 0.3490000069141388, 
0.6859999895095825, 0.1679999977350235, 0, 0, 
0.2720000147819519, 0.5339999794960022, 
0.1309999972581863, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
```

Online color transform generators can help for real time tuning:

Online matrix generator:
http://www.onebyonedesign.com/flash/matrixGenerator/

[image]

Comment: Can I find a dump of existing ColorMatrixFilters someplace?

Comment: @summers I'm not aware of a compilation of presets.